# Btree index and Bit Map Index

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, btree, bitmap-index

Please clarify the difference between BitMap Index and Btree index. I am using mysql version 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.

I can able to create Btree index but unable to create the same,

Please find the below query for Btree index which has been created.

****mysql> CREATE INDEX emp_id_index ON employee_details (emp_id) USING BTREE;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
   Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0****

Please find the below query for Bitmap Index which is showing error

****mysql> CREATE BITMAP INDEX index_name ON employee_details (emp_name); 
   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BITMAP INDEX index_name ON employee_details (emp_name)' at line 1****

Please guide me what i had done wrong in the Bitmap query.

Also let me know whats the difference between these two index. I had gone through the below link but not able to find the apt one.

**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html**
**http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1524**

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Answer by Mat provided in a [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71808/btree-index-and-bit-map-index#comment129043_71808) to the question:</sub>

The second link isn't documentation. It's a feature request. It's someone requesting that bitmap indexes be added to MySQL. It's not something that exists, it will potentially exist in future versions.